# Masstransit+ RabbitMQ. Share one queue among two different message types

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, messaging, masstransit

I have a publisher, which publishes messages to **rabbitmq://localhost/test123** queue. One message has TestMessage type, the other TestMessage2 type.

Publisher config:

```
 sbc.UseRabbitMq(r => r.ConfigureHost(new MessageUrn("rabbitmq://localhost/test123"), c => { }));
 sbc.UseLog4Net();
 sbc.UseJsonSerializer();
 sbc.EnableMessageTracing();
 sbc.ReceiveFrom(new MessageUrn("rabbitmq://localhost/test123"));
```

I have two seprate consumers per message type (2 consumers), consumer 1:

```
  //config stuff
  sbc.ReceiveFrom("rabbitmq://localhost/test678?prefetch=20");
  sbc.Subscribe(subs => { subs.Handler<TestMessage>(msg => { Logger.Info(msg.Text); }); });
```

consumer 2:

```
 //config stuff
 sbc.ReceiveFrom("rabbitmq://localhost/test678");
            sbc.Subscribe(
                subs =>
                {
                    subs.Handler<TestMessage2>(
                        msg => { Logger.Info(String.Format("rcv:txt= {0}, number= {1}", msg.Text, msg.Number)); });
                });
```

So when I stop publisher and run one of the consumers, he consumes all messages of his type and move other to error queue. Exchange for test678 has bindings for both types.

Is it normal behavior that 2 different consumers will try to read their message while moving other messages to error queue? Why I can't share one queue among different consumers with different interested types?

(I believe it is not masstransit issue, rather rabbitmq design considerations or limitation)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more than one service bus instance receiving from the same queue, you need to ensure that the consumers registered on that service bus instance are the same. Otherwise, messages consumed by the service will be moved to the _error queue for message type which have no consumer on that service instance.

Comment: Thank you very much, Chris. One more question: is that because queue (rabbitmq in this case) pushing message to consumer? So  if  consumer doesn't know how to handle this message type he moves it to error queue. I belive that if there were polling from consumer side such situation could be avoided...

Comment: There is no such thing as polling and it wouldn't matter anyway as RMQ doesn't discriminate message types.